# How to fix iOS crash " com.apple.main-thread SIGABRT ABORT"

Tags: ios, crash, quartz-core

I'm facing a crash occured 10 times from fabric log. But I can't reproduce it when connecting Xcode.

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib  __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380
2   libsystem_c.dylib   abort + 140
3   QuartzCore  CA::Render::Encoder::encode_object_uncached(CA::Render::Object const*) + 366
4   QuartzCore  CA::Render::Encoder::encode_data_async(void const*, unsigned long, void (*)(void const*, void*), void*) + 212
5   QuartzCore  CA::Render::Image::encode(CA::Render::Encoder*) const + 636
6   QuartzCore  CA::Render::Layer::encode(CA::Render::Encoder*) const + 128
7   QuartzCore  CA::Render::encode_set_object(CA::Render::Encoder*, unsigned long, unsigned int, CA::Render::Object*, unsigned int) + 192
8   QuartzCore  CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 484
9   QuartzCore  CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
10  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
11  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
12  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
13  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
14  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
15  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
16  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
17  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::commit_if_needed(CA::Transaction*, void (*)(CA::Layer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void*), void*) + 260
18  QuartzCore  CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 3028
19  QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::commit() + 640
20  QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
21  CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
22  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 412
23  CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1228
24  CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
25  GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 104
26  UIKitCore   UIApplicationMain + 212
27  ChopeDashboard  main.m line 14 main + 14
28  libdyld.dylib   start + 4
```

Do you guys know how to resolve it? 
Thanks very much!

Comment: Anything in common about the type of device that’s crashing?

Comment: is it showing any specific file and line number in fabric?, can you please share some piece of code around it?

Comment: @matt Just found 2 types: ipad 5, ipad Air 2

Comment: @atul No, so i don't know show which code.

Comment: Are you able to find any user flow from fabric logs? This may help in trim down the search area.

Comment: @atul No, this kind of crash is blind.